# Vue3: how to mix composition api and options api for composable/mixin namespacing

Tags: vuejs3, composable

Good day!

Let's say I want to use Vue with options api but also do not want to use mixins as they causes a lot of problem. I want to use composables as mixins to give namespacing for mixins/composables.

So, my "solution" was to combine options api and composition api.

Let's say I have a mixin like this:

```
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      person: {
        first_name: 'first name',
        last_name: 'last name',
      },
      gender: 'gender'
    }
}
```

So I decided to convert it into a composable as follows:

```
export default () => {
  const person = reactive({first_name: 'fn', last_name: 'ln'});
  const gender = ref('gender');
  
  return {
    person,
    gender,
  }
}
```

So, in my .vue file I can import the composable:

```
<script lang="ts">
import useDataComposable from './dataMixin';
...

export default defineComponent({
  ...
  setup() {
    const dataComposable = useDataComposable();
    dataComposable.gender.value = 'gender2';
    dataComposable.person.first_name = 'first name2';

    return {dataComposable};
  },
  created() {
    // I want to use data and methods inside the composable as namespace.attribute
    // eg:
    console.log(this.dataComposable.person.first_name) // => returns 'first name2'
 
    // However,
    console.log(this.dataComposable.gender // does not return 'gender2';
      // but returns Ref object.
...
```

I know that I can destructure the composable in the setup function and return it:

```
<script lang="ts">
import useDataComposable from './dataMixin';
...

export default defineComponent({
  ...
  setup() {
    const {person, gender}= useDataComposable();

    return {
      person, gender,
    };
  },
  created() {
    console.log(this.person.first_name) // => returns 'first name2'
 
    // However,
    console.log(this.gender // returns 'gender2';
...
```

However, there is no point to it, as it is anyway it is going to be mixed up with component state.

Also, I could just use mixins with only one object, but I am not sure about it.

```
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      state: {
        person: {
          first_name: 'first name',
          last_name: 'last name',
        },
        gender: 'gender',
        
        myMethod: function() {...},
        computed: function() {...}
      },
      
      created() {...},
      onMounted() {...},
      watch: {
        gender(value) {...}.
      },
    }
}
```

I am curious whether it is possible to do what I want.

**Is there any way to use object with reactive and ref elements from composable in options api vue code?**

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You could either:
destructure and add return { namespace:  { person, gender} }
Change the composable to return a reactive that contains both person and gender.